# Having issues with getting root path directory from different folders

Tags: php, redirect, root

I am trying to connect a certain header file for different files in different folders. The problem is when having the same file included in for example /backend it will be easily called directly (as the index is also in /backend) but when calling it from backend/pages it doesnt recall the link structure anymore resulting in a deadlink.

I have tried every possible thing with ../ and different header files but that is a no go. Trying to find a solution such as the url below comes really close but yet I cannot seem to figure it.

[Root path variable in a PHP project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38867220/root-path-variable-in-a-php-project)

What would be the best way to include the root automatically in an include or require for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a front controller (like an index.php file) that is starting and executing your entire application you can just set a constant there like `define('APP_ROOT', __DIR__);` and that'll set the root to be your front controller.

You can access your header file from anywhere then by doing `APP_ROOT . "/includes/header.php"`

If you are not using a front controller, then you can set this in each file. So for backend/pages it'd be something like `./../includes/header.php`. or better still, use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to get the root of your application as provided by your web server vhosts config. (Apache of NGINX most likely)

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/app/backend/includes/header.php"` for example.

Comment: That would probably be a better idea indeed ill try and see what I can make from this ^^

Comment: I tried this but when I add either: 

   $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'backend/leftmenu.php'; ?>  
or <?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'backend/leftmenu.php'; ?> it deletes the entire menu

Comment: Have you tried testing the result of $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']? Try just doing a `var_dump($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])` and see what it gives you. then you can work from there to complete the URI to your file. Check for things like maybe you have two forward slashes next to each other, or maybe you have none where there should be one. Build the URI piece by piece until it works with one of your files and you'll see how to fix the rest too :)

Comment: I must say these things are a bit new for me at this moment. I am not so much yet familiar with this side of php it looks more modern then the PHP I am used to work with. I think ill manage it but I just need to figure a few things before I get there.

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the best way to include the root automatically in an include or require for example.

I'm not aware of any method to do that without modifying PHP itself and re-compiling from source, but I could be wrong. Your root path will always be stored in `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

I think what you might want to look into is [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) and more specifically [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) and [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading).

Comment: Wouldnt it be possible to load $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in <?php include somehow?  that way it still has to be done manually with every file but atleast will allow one header to be included in different folder structures in my opinion of logic.

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned, the only method that I know of is to modify the source code of PHP and re-compile it, which is very undesirable for a multitude of reasons.